# How to implement correctly checking the set of keys through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to check if key exists in DB via ajax.
But I will have a lot of checkings all over the site.

What is the best way?

If I will have 50 checking on the page my script will send 50 queries. I dont think that this is good way.

Comment: You have control of the server side code as well?

Comment: Can you collect all IDs and perform a single ajax call on document::ready?

Comment: I decided to use localStorage